# ServiceStack ServiceStack.Auth.OrmLiteAuthRepository

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

All of a sudden I got the following error message when I try to run my web application. "Method 'GetRolesAndPermissions' in type 'ServiceStack.Auth.OrmLiteAuthRepository`2' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Server, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation." I have not updated anything (myself at least). Does anybody recognize the error message? I do not know what I should provide to make this problem reproducible. As I do not know what triggered the issue, and therefore I do not know what is relevant, and it is rather hard to include the entire project in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `GetRolesAndPermissions` was added in the latest [ServiceStack v5.6](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.6) Release. This Exception occurs if you have a dirty mix of trying to use different NuGet versions together, make sure **all your ServiceStack dependencies reference the same version**, e.g. by upgrading them all to v5.6.

You can tell if your solution is still referencing old versions by deleting your NuGet **packages** folder:

```
rd /q /s packages
```

Then restoring the NuGet packages in your solution, then check the **packages** folder to make sure all ServiceStack packages are referencing the same version. If you have different NuGet versions in the packages folder you still have some projects referencing older package versions which need to be upgraded.

Comment: Idd that was the case. The "main" project was using a later version than the rest of the solution. However, any idea on how the interface and service project got updated, and not the main solution?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen No, but if you update you should update packages from the solution then make sure that all ServiceStack packages are upgraded to the same version, it's easy to forget to upgrade all packages. But whenever you have missing method exceptions like this, it's an indication that not all packages were upgraded.